# Vertx get event loop msg number

Tags: java, redhat, vert.x

I'm trying to find a way to get the current number of message that I have in the event loop.

I want to put some logs to know if the message are getting enqueue.

I have this Iterator, but I dont think it is since are `eventExecutor`

```
        Context context = vertx.getOrCreateContext();
        ContextInternal contextInt = (ContextInternal) context;
        EventLoop eventLoop = contextInt.nettyEventLoop();
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the result of `.nettyEventLoop()` as a `NioEventLoop` you can invoke the `.pendingTasks` method that should give you the information about the number of tasks scheduled in the event loop.

```
NioEventLoop eventLoop = (NioEventLoop) ci.nettyEventLoop();
System.out.println(eventLoop.pendingTasks());
```

JavaDoc about `NioEventLoop` implementation:

https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoop.html